# Pass a query parameter with django reverse?

Tags: django

I have a url that is meant to be accessed like

```
/people/raj/updates
/people/raj/updates?tag=food
```

But Django reverse URL resolver seems to have no provision to do `tag=food`, that is to detect it as an extra parameter and put in the query string.

How do I pass query parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question... but this doesn't help? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls (look the args=(year,) parameter)

Answer (score 13):

It depends on whether you are building the URL in the python code or in a template.

In python code (e.g. the view):

```
from django.http import QueryDict

query_dictionary = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
query_dictionary.update(
    {
        'tag': 'food'
    }
)
url = '{base_url}?{querystring}'.format(
    base_url=reverse(my.url.name),
    querystring=query_dictionary.urlencode()
)
```

And in a template:

```
<a href="{% url 'my.url.name' %}?tag=food">My Link</a>
```

You caould also pass the QueryDict object from the view to the template and use that when building the URL in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'my.url.name' %}?{{ query_dictionary.urlencode }}">My Link</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

Django's reverse does not include GET or POST parameters. They are not part of the url.

You can of course always create the url by, for instance in a template, attaching the parameter as in:

```
{% url 'named_url' %}?tag=food
```

This way it gets attached anyway. Alternative is building an url regex that includes the possible tag, like:

```
url(r'^/people/raj/updates/(?P<tag>[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)?', yourview())
```

This way you can check for the kwarg tag in your view.