# How to create a Django reverse url with a parameter

Tags: django

I am having problems constructing a reverse url with a parameter

I have tried the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864935/pass-a-query-parameter-with-django-reverse) but with no luck

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('publication-item/<str:publication_title>', PublicationItemView.as_view(), name='publication-item'),
]
```

**xxx.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'publication-item {{ publication.publication_title | urlencode }}' %}">
```

gives the error

> Reverse for 'publication-item {{ publication.publication_title | urlencode }}' not found. 'publication-item {{ publication.publication_title | urlencode }}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Whereas

**xxx.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'publication-item' %}?publication_title={{ publication.publication_title | urlencode }}">
```

produces

> Reverse for 'publication-item' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['publicationspublication\-item/(?P<publication_title>[^/]+)$']

The following works, but of course it doesn't pass the parameter

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('publication-item', PublicationItemView.as_view(), name='publication-item'),
]
```

**xxx.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'publication-item' %}" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use double curly brackets, you are already in a template tag, hence Django will interpret the variable:

```
<a href="{% url 'publication-item' publication.publication_title %}">
```

You do not need to URL encode yourself, Django will automatically URL encode the parameters.